# Removing "," (comma) value from the columns of a CSV file using linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, csv

I'm having a CSV file with 5 columns where 1 column is having integer values like (1,564, 4,789, 9,765). I need to remove "," (comma) from col3 where integer value should look like as follows: (1564,4789,9865).

Tried various ways using "awf" & "sed"
but none of it is working.
Below is the sample input and expected output.
Input CSV file:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
Abcd,defg,"1,432",hjik,khuj
```

Output CSV file:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
Abcd,defg,"1432",hjik,khuj
```

Comment: Your csv is broken. If the field contains the separator character, the field must be quoted. See section 2.6 of [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180). (Other flavors of csv may have different quoting mechanisms, but they must have one.) You need to fix the program that generates the invalid csv.

Comment: If fixing the broken csv producer is not an option, at least always include your attempts / code you've tried to solve the problem; see [ask].

Comment: I **hope** your separator is actually "comma, space" (as in your first example) and not "comma". If it is, things might be salvagable... or is column 3 the only numerical one / the only one potentially including embedded commas? We need more precise data.

Comment: If there's only one column that can have embedded commas, you can count commas from the left and right to get the other columns. Then everything in the middle is the broken column.

Answer (score 1):

This regex **might** help you find the unquoted fields:

```
(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)
```

and with a simple replacement, like `"\1"`, properly quote them.

It looks for "1-3 digits, followed by some number of sequences of a comma and three digits".

I say **might** because you've only shown one small sample of the data, and this only works on numbers sensibly separated with commas.

I started with this broken CSV:

```
col1,col2,col3
a,1,b
a,12,b
a,123,b
a,1,234,b
a,12,345,b
a,123,456,b
a,1,234,567,b
```

and got this:

```
| c1 | c2        | c3 |
|----|-----------|----|
| a  | 1         | b  |
| a  | 12        | b  |
| a  | 123       | b  |
| a  | 1,234     | b  |
| a  | 12,345    | b  |
| a  | 123,456   | b  |
| a  | 1,234,567 | b  |
```

You can see it in action here, [regexr.com/7ht81](https://regexr.com/7ht81):

[image: regexr find and quoting broken fields]

This small Python program will fix my sample CSV:

```py
import re

lines: list[str] = []
with open("input.csv", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        fixed = re.sub(r"(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)", '"\\1"', line)
        lines.append(fixed)

with open("output.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fist replace the commas you want to keep with `\r`, next remove the others.
Finally restore the commas.

```
sed -r 's/([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*),([^,]*),([^,]*)/\1\r\2\r\3\r\4\r\5/;s/,//g;s/\r/,/g' input.csv
```

EDIT:
As Zach commented, you might want to replace all `\r` with `|||||`. On Linux you expect only `\n` characters, but a csv format is often generated on Windows.

Comment: Maybe instead of something common-enough, like `\r`, use `|||||` ("five bars") as the placeholder? Otherwise, I really like that regex: two sets of anything but a comma, with a trailing comma, then everything up to more sets of the previous.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CSV aware tool as [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.0/installing-miller/).

Running

```
mlr --csv put '$col3=gsub($col3,",","")' input.csv >output.csv
```

you get

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
Abcd,defg,1432,hjik,khuj
```

- `put` is the verb to apply functions.
- `gsub` is the function that substitutes `,` with nothing in `col3`

Answer (score -3):

use below to replace comma with space,dot or anything

```
#!/bin/sh

read filename

#replace all_occurrence(g) of  comma with .
sed 's/,/./g' "$filename" >> output.csv
```

Comment: That will replace all commas. OP wants to replace on the comma-as-data in the 3rd column and leave all the delimiting commas alone.